# Doubt on finding the area of a triangle formed by the tips of vectors

Tags: vectors

Question :

> Find the area of a triangle formed by  the tips of vectors    a=
> i-j-3k , b= 4i-3j+k  ,  c= 3i-j+ 2k.

Fig 1 is the representation of the triangle.

Fig 2 and 3 show my solution

[image]

Solution in the book

> In the book , first **a** - **b** was found .
>
> **a** - **b** = -3**i** +2**j** -4**k**
>
> then **c** - **b**  was found.
>
> **c** - **b** = -**i** + 2**j** + **k**
>
> Then (**a** - **b**)X (**a** - **b** )
> =10**i** + 7**j** - 4**k**
>
> In the book , the magnitude of this cross product was stated as the area ofthe
> parallelogram formed in Fig 1.Halving the magnitude gave the area of the      triangle.
> Final answer : 6.4 sq unit

But I cannot understand why was the cross product  of                         (**a** - **b**) and  (**c** - **b** ) found .

**My solution is as under** :

Fig 2 shows my opinion.

> The area of the parallelogram in fig 1 is the same as the area of the
> parallelogram formed between vectors **a** and **c** as in fig 2.
>
> This is shown in Fig 3.
>
> **a** X **c** = -5**i** -8**j** - 4**k**
>
> Then the magnitude of cross product of  **a** and **c** should give
> the area of  the  parallelogram.

But I know my solution is incorrect.

I cannot understand why is it incorrect.

Please provide me the explanation.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

The vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ start from the origin. So what you have designated as $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{c}$ in the second figure are actually the vectors $\vec{a} - \vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}-\vec{b}$. Your method is correct, provided that the bottom left hand corner of the parallelogram is actually the origin, i.e. $\vec{b} = \vec{0}$.

Comment: Thank you. But  I am still confused as to how      a⃗ − b⃗  =  a⃗ .  Also by my method , I am not getting the right answer. Could you please explain a little more. Thank you once again.